# Webgrid not displaying data MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, webgrid

I am trying to display model data in webgrid. I see that @grid has two rows in it, but nothing is displayed. Unable to figure out what is causing this to happen even though there is data in @grid.
I am trying to display one column just to test, but I also tried displaying all columns using @grid.GetHtml(), still nothing is shown in the UI. Any pointers is appreciated!

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Domain.Entities.Tests>
    @{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             @if (Model.Count() > 0)
            {
               @grid.GetHtml(
               columns:grid.Columns(
               grid.Column(columnName:"Capacity",header:"Capacity")
              ))
            }
            else
            {
               <div>Please select slots and right click on context menu to view attributes.</div>
             }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I did some debugging with firebug, the surprising thing is that it is dispalying the value in the post request             <table class="webGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Home/ViewAttributes?sort=Slot_Num&amp;sortdir=ASC">Slot_Num</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>. It is not displaying on the page

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. I was putting the ajax datatype as json and I was returning partialview result. I changed the datatype in ajax post request to html. I also added a new function setData(data) and loaded the div with the html returned by ajax request. Hope this helps someone who might be doing the same mistake as me.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/ViewAttributes1",
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        SetData(data);
                    },
                    **dataType: "html",** (changed from json to html)
                    traditional: true
                });
                **added this function in which I am loading the div with the data returned by ajax**
                function SetData(data)
                {
                        $("#viewAttribs").html(data); // HTML DOM replace
                    }
```